# Change div/button depending on variable value

Tags: php, html, arrays, if-statement, button

My problem is this I have this variable

> $tpl_dat['col']['mng_chp']

If this variable is 1 want to display a div with read now if this variable is 2 i want to display 2 div one with read now one with read now 2 and if this variable is 0 i want to display a div with not available.
My actual code is this but only display the same div for all the values >=1 and antoher div is is =0:

```
   <div class="read-now">
        <?php if(count($tpl_dat['col']['mng_chp'])){ ?>
            <?php foreach($tpl_dat['col']['mng_chp'] as $chp){ ?>
                   <a class="lst" href="<?php echo $chp['url']; ?>" >
                    <div class="btn-read-now">Read Now</div></a>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
            <?php } ?>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                    <div class="btn-available">Not Available</div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
            ?php } ?>
    </div>
```

The other div is:

> Read Now2

Comment: you never actually test the value. you just test if it's true-ish/false-ish. you need `if ($var == 1) { ... } else if ($var == 2) { ... } else { ....}`

Comment: I would use a switch case (http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: the problem with if else if and else is that i can't check the array value with the foreach that does the function foreach($tpl_dat['col']['mng_chp'] as $chp) and recall it for the url $chp['url']

Comment: Side note. PHP has this great templating feature where you can do: `<?php if (cond): ?> Any HTML you want here <?php endif; ?>` Its much easier to read than single braces all over. You can do the same for loops